# Checking $|z|^2$ complex differentiability with definition only

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

So I want to check if $|z|^2$ is complex differentiable. I did not want to use Cauchy-Riemann ODE since we did not have it in the lecture. What I tried is a bit weird and I know that I did a mistake somewhere, but can't figure out where exactly. I want to use the definition only:

$$
\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} = \lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{x^2+y^2-x_0^2-y_0^2}{(x+iy)-(x_0+iy_0)}
$$

now this looks pretty ugly. So I would try to splitt it:

i) $z_1= x_0+iy$ with $y\rightarrow y_0$ (vertical)

ii) $z_2=x+iy_0$ with $x\rightarrow x_0$ (horizontal)

We get:

i) $$
\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z_1)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} = \lim_{y\rightarrow y_0} \frac{y^2-y_0^2}{i(y-y_0)}=\lim_{y\rightarrow y_0} \frac{y+y_0}{i}
=\frac{2y_0}{i}$$

ii) $$
\lim_{z\rightarrow z_0} \frac{f(z_2)-f(z_0)}{z-z_0} = \lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} \frac{x^2-x_0^2}{(x-x_0)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow x_0} x+x_0
=2x_0$$

Well now it has to be $\frac{2y_0}{i}=2x_0$. But this is only the case if... $x_0=y_0=0$? It definitly is the case for $0$ but how can I show that it is only the case for $0$? Is the rest right and if not, where is the mistake?

Comment: $|z|^2$ is not complex differentiable (the only complex differentiable functions of $z$ whose values are real for all $z$ are constant functions).  Your analysis of the behaviour in vertical and horizontal directions looks right to me and shows that the function is not complex differentiable.

Comment: What you did is perfectly fine Note that $2y_0/i=2x_0$ simply implies $y_0=ix$. It is perfectly alright to note that $|z|^2$ actually *does* admit a complex derivative along the line spanned by $(1,i)$. In complex analysis we just tend to be interested in functions that are complex differentiable on an open set, as that's where power of the theory actually kicks in.

Comment: Thank you both.